# running bash from matlab

Tags: python, bash, matlab

I am trying to run a bash file from matlab that exectes a python file. If I simply run the bash from the terminal using:

```
source test_bash.sh
```

It runs fine. However, when I run from matlab:

```
system('source test_bash.sh')
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named unidecode
```

I don't understand the difference between running the same bash file from the terminal and from Matlab (using system()).

Comment: Can you share the python gist

Comment: its a python script that does some text editing and refomatting and than run a force-alignment script that uses htk. However, it seems to stack at the second line of the script when trying to import unidecode

Comment: How are you starting matlab? Is it from an environment that has all the variables/paths/etc defined that are required to run the python script?

Comment: how do I make sure that they have the same environment?

Comment: @user552231 Start matlab from a shell that has everything needed by the python script defined.

Answer (score 2):

The path you are running the matlab script seems unable to find the python packages(in our case `unidecode` package)

Try to run the script from the path exactly, the shell runs from

Incase if you want to add an environment variable in matlab to achieve the above use `setenv(name,value)` method & try to run the matlab script again

Comment: Lets do one thing, before trying to run the shell script lets run the python script from matlab. Can you run `system('/path/to/my/venv/bin/python myscript.py')`test it works or not.

Comment: It returned the same error (dont find unidecode package)